# Is there a open source OpenGL implementation for MS Windows?

Tags: windows, opengl

As the title asks,

Is there an open source OpenGL implementation for MS Windows?

Not such an example code that using opengl, but the one that gives opengl32.dll after building.

Comment: You mean software implementation of GL? Mesa (http://www.mesa3d.org/) could be used for this, but why?

Comment: mesa openGL implementation can run on MS Windows? I trying to understand the internals how MS Windows and OpenGL libs work.

Comment: http://www.mesa3d.org/install.html says that it can be built for windows, yes. But software implementation and driver that maps commands to graphics hardware - are two completely different things. In software mode, it will result in generating ordinary 2d image and displaying it, regardless of OS.

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First and foremost you must understand that OpenGL *is not* a library, but an API specification. Libraries may implement this API. But normally OpenGL is implemented by the GPU device driver.

The `opengl32.dll` ships as part of Windows. All Windows Versions since WindowsNT-4 and Windows95-B ship with the `opengl32.dll` as part of the base installation. It acts as a conduit for programs that make use of OpenGL to talk to the GPU drivers that actually implement it. *The OpenGL magic does not happen in the `opengl32.dll` but in the GPU drivers!* There's a mechanism called the [OpenGL ICD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff568203%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which the GPU drivers use to hook their OpenGL stuff into the DLL.

> Is there an open source OpenGL implementation for MS Windows?

Well yes, Mesa3D also can be built for Windows, but the resulting DLL will not be able to talk to the GPU drivers, but merely implement all OpenGL functionality through a software renderer. In Linux Mesa3D also implements the device drivers for a number of GPUs, but those drivers require kernel interfaces specific to Linux and are not portable (however other open source operating systems like FreeBSD adopted the Linux kernel APIs Mesa3D uses, so it works there as well).

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different from what you asked - if you are ok with OpenGL ES2, a nice solution is to have ANGLE setup. This is an open source implementation of OpenGL ES2.0 on Windows platforms, but it uses DirectX API internally to map to GL calls. It is fairly easy to setup with full debug support, as mentioned here (http://gpupowered.org/node/29), and with GLFW support here (http://gpupowered.org/node/33).